# What causes "Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread creation via pthread_create() failed." in Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, nltk

I had made a discord bot in python and have now added "Chatbot" feature in it using Tensorflow and NLTK. When I run the bot locally, it works absolutely fine without any issues but when I move it to my namecheap hosting package where I host my portfolio, it starts to give an error by saying :

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 29 of 64: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and nltk and tensorflow don't get imported and the bot crashes.

I googled it and found a solution which tells to use `os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'` before using any imports. This solved the previous error but now it gives another error saying:

```
Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread creation via pthread_create() failed.
```

The complete output on running `python main.py` now is:

```
2021-06-10 11:18:19.606471: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-06-10 11:18:19.606497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-06-10 11:18:21.090650: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-06-10 11:18:21.090684: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-06-10 11:18:21.090716: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (server270.web-hosting.com): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-06-10 11:18:21.091042: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-06-10 11:18:21.092409: F tensorflow/core/platform/default/env.cc:73] Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread creation via pthread_create() failed.
```

To not make this question too long, the source files have already been hosted on GitHub here: https://github.com/Nalin-2005/The2020CoderBot And the `README.md` tells which files contain which part of the bot.

The bot is being hosted on Namecheap shared hosting and the details and technical specs about the server are:

- RAM: 1GB
- Storage: 20GB SSD
- CPU (used `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq`):  Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6140 CPU @ 2.30GHz

As per my knowledge, both the issues are caused by limited RAM or CPU usage. But now, the Python script itself blocks the usage.
So, what causes this (If I am not correct) and how can I fix this?

Comment: maybe you will have to buy server with more resources? Did you check how many RAM is used when you run it on local computer?

Comment: @furas It used quite less RAM on my laptop but probably the server could not handle it. No problem, i found the solution myself after some brainstorming... To use Tensorflow Lite !!! And it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time brainstorming and googling, i found Tensorflow Lite and it consumes less resources but offering the same performance* on my server and i could easily integrate it with the previous code to produce a more resource-efficient model.
To the users who would want to know how to convert any keras model to Tensorflow lite, here are the instructions.

1. While training, replace `model.save("/path/to/model.h5")` with:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open("/path/to/model.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

2. While using, use:

```py
model = tf.lite.Interpreter("/path/to/model.tflite")
model.allocate_tensors()
input_details = model.get_input_details()
output_details = model.get_output_details()

# prepare input data

model.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
model.invoke()
output_data = model.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
results = np.squeeze(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and solved it by refactoring my code. Check that you don`t overload your RAM - if you run some function inside loop and you import some heavy data you can write them localy to file, to reduce RAM needed for processing.