# Keras and Tensorflow OS resource requirement

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I keep getting `F tensorflow/core/platform/default/env.cc:73] Check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)Thread tf_data_private_threadpool creation via pthread_create() failed.` errors during training, although the machine is quite powerful:

```
memory size: 256GiB
2 pieces of AMD EPYC 7302 16-Core Processor
8 pieces of NVIDIA A2
```

altogether 64 logical cores

ulimit -s gives 32768,
ulimit -u gives 1030608

I want to train the following network with a bunch of online generated 512*512 grayscale images along with two additional parameters for each image. Image generation happens in a C++ function called via Pybind11. The C++ function itself is not resource-hungry.

This is my very first AI training code, so it is just copied from some similar application with parameters adjusted. I need the relatively high resolution, because the network needs to learn infer a real number from a small repeated part of the image.

The situation is the same when I leave only the CNN part of the model, without the concatenation. Moreover, I've counted the processes createrd during run. The crash happens around **31000 pytnon3 processes of me** which I find extreme. Meanwhile nvidia-smi reports around 13G memory consumption on only one of the GPUs.

```py
# this one in module landscapeGenerator
def generate(aBatchSize:int=32, aRepeatParameter:int=2):
  dim = (512, 512)
  paraShape = (aRepeatParameter * 2)
  def generator():
    xParameter = numpy.empty(paraShape, dtype=float)
    xImage     = numpy.empty(aDim, dtype=float)
    y          = numpy.empty((1), dtype=float)
# set parameters, use them to obtain the image via Pybind11
    xImage = randomLandscape(dist, height, tempAmb, tempBase)
    xParameter[0] = xImage[0, 0] / 0.04  # Field of view is at most 0.04 radians
    xImage[0, 0]  = xImage[0, 1]
    xParameter[aRepeatParameter] = something
    for i in range(1, aRepeatParameter):
      xParameter[i] = xParameter[0]
      xParameter[aRepeatParamter + i] = xParameter[aRepeatParameter]
    y[0]          = something
    yield {"parameters": xParameters, "image": xImage}, y

  dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate,
    output_signature=(
      (tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=paraShape, dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="parameters"),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=dim, dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="image")),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(1), dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="y")
            ))
  dataset = dataset.batch(aBatchSize)
  return dataset

def createMlp(aRepeatParameter:int=2):
  model = Sequential()
  vectorSize = aRepeatParameter * 2
  model.add(Dense(vectorSize, input_dim=(vectorSize), activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(aRepeatParameter, activation="relu"))
  return model

def createCnn():
  filters=(512, 128, 32)
  inputShape = (512, 512, 1)
  chanDim = -1
  inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
  for (i, f) in enumerate(filters):
    if i == 0:
      x = inputs
    x = Conv2D(f, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(16)(x)
  x = Activation("relu")(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Dense(4)(x)
  x = Activation("relu")(x)
  model = Model(inputs, x)
  return model

repeatParameter:int = 2
mlp = createMlp(repeatParameter)
cnn = createCnn()
combinedInput = concatenate([mlp.output, cnn.output])
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(combinedInput)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs=[mlp.input, cnn.input], outputs=x)

opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)

batchSize = 32
model.fit(landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter), validation_data=landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter),
  epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=10, validation_split=0.3)

model.save('trainAiTemp.model')
```

What could I do to let it run?

Comment: Discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929842/what-causes-check-failed-ret-0-11-vs-0thread-creation-via-pthread-create. But this seems to suggest it's memory limits, which seems a bit unlikely on the server you are using.

Comment: I don't think the linked case is similar to mine. I've noted that the training runs on my own machine with just 8 GB RAM and an NVidia GTX1060.

Comment: If stack size is large, it's possible for this to limit the number of threads a process can start. Unlikely maybe, but might be worth checking. What gets returned from  ulimit -a | grep "stack size"?

Comment: Good idea, but no luck even if I set `ulimit -s 192`. It dumps core with 128. Following your idea I will limit the amount of GPUs to use if I find out how to.

Comment: If this is a server, consider that your queueing system or sysadmin might put limits in your user account, you should be asking this to your admins, not us.

Comment: This was the first thing I've asked. No strict limits, like /etc/security/limits.conf is empty. I also wanted to search for Tensorflow / Keras OS process requirements, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for everyone. There was a typo in the code resulting in an endless recursion. The process resource exhaustion happened earlier than the stack overflow due to unlimited recursion, that's why it was hard to spot.

```py
def generate(aBatchSize:int=32, aRepeatParameter:int=2):
  dim = (512, 512)
  paraShape = (aRepeatParameter * 2)
  def generator():
    xParameter = numpy.empty(paraShape, dtype=float)
# ...

  dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate,) # ...
# Here the generate referred to the outer function resulting in endless
# recursion. It should have been generator.

  dataset = dataset.batch(aBatchSize)
  return dataset
```